# How to optionally create shortcut in Microsoft Visual Studio Installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer, installation

I am now using Visual Studio 2019 and followed a guide on creating a installer project with the Microsoft Extension for creating installer projects. I've created the main project output, and also shortcuts to the Start menu and Desktop. However, I've got a request to make the shortcut to Desktop optional, but I don't see where to do this anywhere.

Anyone else tackled this problem?

Comment: There is no such option in Microsoft Visual Studio Installer. You can only set whether to create a shortcut.

Comment: @KyleWang thank you, do you happen to know of an installer extension which does this?

Comment: Hope this (via WiX) can help you. [How to create an optional shortcut](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/How-to-create-an-optional-shortcut-td699311.html)

Answer (score 0):

For optional things in Wix Toolset use [Feature element](https://wixtoolset.org//documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/feature.html) from the advanced installer UI.

WXS-Block for Feature

```xml
<Feature Id="StartMenuShortcut" 
             Title="My StartMenuShortcut" Description="Foo Bar ... Shortcut"
             Level="1" AllowAdvertise="no" Display="expand" InstallDefault="local" TypicalDefault="install">
  <ComponentRef Id="ShortcutsStartmenuStartProduct" />
</Feature>
```

WXS-Block for the Shortcut

```xml
<DirectoryRef Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder">
  <Component Guid="nguid" Id="ApplicationShortcut">
    <Shortcut Id="OptionalShortcut"
                  Name="FooBar"
                  Target="BarFoo"/>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Comment: Your answer is for the wrong installer program.  I won't downvote you, but only because the OP asked for options in a comment.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for not down-voting ;-) Anyhow what do you mean with wrong installer program, the tags shows "windows-installer" and I assume that wix toolset is the tool for building windows installers.

Comment: There's an installer project type.  It's called windows installer.